# Why does the object in animation don't move

Tags: animation, rigging, armature, bones, vertex-groups

As you can see I have problem with this one object. I created Vertex Groups(all assigned well), joined all objects into one, added Armature modifiers and this one object don't move with the bone.

I tried to separate this element and set parent to bone, but it didn't help. Also applied Scale and rotation before joining objects

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Sure. Link below screen shot.

Comment: I renamed the bone and the vertex group to "Mid" and it works. So probably this is a bug, something mismatched inside.